# Sklearn+Gensim: How to use Gensim's Word2Vec embedding for Sklearn text classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, gensim

I am building a multilabel text classification program and I am trying to use OneVsRestClassifier+XGBClassifier to classify the text. Initially I used Sklearn's Tf-Idf Vectorization to vectorize the texts, which worked without error. Now I am using **Gensim's Word2Vec** to vectorize the texts. When I feed the vectorized data into the OneVsRestClassifier+XGBClassifier however, I get the following error on the line where I split the test and training data:

> TypeError: Singleton array array(,
>         dtype=object) cannot be considered a valid collection.

I have tried converting the vectorized data into a feature array (np.array), but that hasn't seemed to work.
Below is my code:

```
x = np.array(Word2Vec(textList, size=120, window=6, min_count=5, workers=7, iter=15))

vectorizer2 = MultiLabelBinarizer()
vectorizer2.fit(tagList)
y = vectorizer2.transform(tagList)

# Split test data and convert test data to arrays
xTrain, xTest, yTrain, yTest = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.20)
```

The variables `textList` and `tagList` are a list of strings (textual descriptions I am trying to classify).

Answer (score 2):

`x` here becomes a numpy array conversion of the `gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec` object -- it is not actually the word2vec representations of `textList` that are returned.

Presumably, what you want to return is the corresponding vector for each word in a document (for a single vector representing each document, it would be better to use [Doc2Vec](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/doc2vec.html)).

For a set of documents in which the most verbose document contains `n` words, then, each document would be represented by an n * 120 matrix.

Unoptimized code for illustrative purposes:

```
import numpy as np

model = x = Word2Vec(textList, size=120, window=6, 
                               min_count=5, workers=7, iter=15)

documents = []
for document in textList:
    word_vectors = []
    for word in document.split(' '): # or your logic for separating tokens
        word_vectors.append(model.wv[word])
    documents.append(np.concatenate(word_vectors))

# resulting in an n * 120 -- that is, `Word2Vec:size`-- array
document_matrix = np.concatenate(documents)
```